# How to specify the total hits of an elastic search results?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to lift my search's hit limit to beyond 10,000, I can achieve this by specifying "track_total_hits: true", but that doesn't exactly allow me to set this limit to say a higher number like 20,000 or 30,000. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The limit can be lifted, by following index setting `index.max_result_window` https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html

Answer (score 0):

As Krithick S said in their comment, if you can and want to increase the amount of results from the cluster side, you can do it by adjusting [the setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html#:%7E:text=the%20refresh%20interval.-,index.max_result_window,-The%20maximum%20value). However, increasing this amount will increase the cluster's memory usage.

For a more efficient option there's [Scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#scroll-search-results) (not recommended anymore as said on that page) and [Search After](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after). Additional to Search After, if you need to keep the index's state frozen while you fetch the documents, you can use Search After with a [Point in Time (PIT)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html).